# Modx get TV field from js

Tags: php, mysql, modx

Делаю сайт на CMS Modx Revo и нужно сделать для каждой страницы ссылку которую будет получать пользователь на сайте при определенных действиях (должна получаться асинхронно с бд с помощью JS). Можно ли как то получить TV переменную от текущего отображаемого ресурса?

*Для примера*: есть TV переменная **file_url**, которую настраивает человек в админке, пользователь заходит на сайт нажимает кнопку *Получить файл* (проверяется определенное условие - другой скрипт не связан с модх) и если условие истинно - отправить запрос к бд на получение переменной **file_url** от текущего ресурса

Answer (score 1):

Например, так: создаете сниппет с кодом(ниже), размещаете его на странице, делаете к ней AJAX запрос, передав ID требуемого ресурса:

```
$page = $modx->getObject('modResource', 123); //  ID ресурса = 123 
return $page->getTVValue('file_url');
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, нашел еще одно решение, но оно вне сниппетов